# Dockerfile: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main' - Dist folder does not exists on container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having the following error when trying to execute my `NestJS` App with `Docker`:

```
> svc-metrics@0.0.1 start:prod
> node dist/main

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16.14.2 as production

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli
RUN npm i --save-dev @types/node
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

COPY . .

#RUN ls #dist folder does not exists here

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

However, if I run `RUN ls` the `dist` folder does not exists and the command `node dist/main` will not work.

Comment: You need to copy the source code before building, so `COPY . .` and `RUN npm run build` should be swapped.

Comment: @HansKilian I've tryied it but still the same error

Comment: try run main instead dist/main on last step? 
CMD ["node", "main"]